# For Loops how to use break

Tags: python, list, loops

I was completing the Loops exercises on CodeAcademy but couldn't figure out what was wrong with my code

### Exercise: Over 9000

- Create a function that sums the elements of a list but stops once the sum is greater than 9000 - return this sum
- If all elements do not reach the sum of 9000 - return its sum
- If the list is empty - return 0

### My Code

What is wrong with the code, it seems to return `None` when it should return `9020`?

```
#Write your function here

def over_nine_thousand(lst):
    max_sum = 0
    for i in lst:
        max_sum += i
    sum = 0
    for num in lst:
        sum += num
        if sum > 9000:
            break
            return sum
        elif sum == max_sum:
            return max_sum
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return 0


#Uncomment the line below when your function is done

print(over_nine_thousand([8000, 900, 120, 5000]))
```

Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you asked for a better way to solve your problem:

```
def over_nine_thousand(lst):
    total = 0
    for x in lst:
        total += x
        if total > 9000:
            return total
    return total

print(over_nine_thousand([8000, 900, 120, 5000]))
```

This iterates through list, adding up values and once it sees the added up value is greater than 9000, a return is fired.

The `return` at the end of loop also handles case if an empty list is passed

Comment: Or, because the question was about break, replace the `return sum` in the `if` under the `for` with `break` so that the `return sum` at the bottom of the function is executed.

Comment: @glglgl That would work and still greatly increase efficiency in comparison to the original. This looks like it's being done in an educational environment so I have a feeling something similar to that is what the instructor would be looking for.

Comment: Austin So using `max_sum` was unnecessary?

Comment: Look at the code in this answer. Yes, it was unnecessary. You needed it because you had an overcomplicated approach.

Comment: @Newbie101, Yes it's unnecessary when you can do it with one variable.

Comment: @glglgl, I agree this might be a case where OP might have to use `break`. But I believe returning at once is better than breaking and return.

Comment: Matthias Yes. I do tend to overcomplicate problems because I struggle to think of simpler ways of doing it.

Comment: *Note*: It's not good to use variable `sum` as it shadows built-in. Use some other name like `total`. Edited mine. :)

Answer (score 3):

You do a break before the return.
Use:

```
   if sum > 9000:
         return sum

 # // 
 if sum > 9000:
        break # Breaks from the for loop
        return sum # This line code will never reached
```